# What is the best way to get ajax loaded content using c#

Tags: ajax, xpath, loaded

I need to get ajax loaded content of an external HTML page using HtmlAgility or Xpath. But some contents are loaded by Ajax from an external resource.

What is the best way to get those contents?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Here is an example script I have posted on my blog that has the general approach and format out for a JSON repsonse type of url endpoint. **
        http://chadcollins.com/create-table-from-json-data/

```
    // set the content type so the browser(s) will buffer the output correctly.
    Response.ContentType = "application/json";

    // create new data access object
    DataAccessObject NewDao = Settings.Connection1DataAccessObject;

    string column_Name = "";
    string innerItems = "";
    string innerProductTypes = "";
    string sqlRowString = "";
    string _pid = Request.QueryString["pid"];
    string innerColumnKeyNames = "";
    string innerColumnKeyValues = "";
    string productTypeFooter = "";

    // check the querystring for the filter key id for the category table Product_Type
    if (_pid != null && _pid.Length != 0) {

    // get columns from the table dynamically. This was the start of an attempt to get the key(column) and row(values) from a standard select below. 
    // ive taken the hardcoded approach for now in setting the product type    
    SqlCommand SelectCol = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 1 *  FROM customtable_Rates_Items",NewDao);
    DataColumnCollection newColumn = SelectCol.Execute().Tables[0].Columns;

            for(int x = 0; x < newColumn.Count; x++){
                    column_Name = newColumn[x].ToString();
                    sqlRowString += column_Name +",";
            }     

    // remove the last , in sqlRowString
    sqlRowString = sqlRowString.TrimEnd(',');

        // Get Items
        SqlCommand Select = new SqlCommand("SELECT "+sqlRowString+" FROM customtable_Rates_Items WHERE Rates_Product_Type_ID="+ 
        NewDao.ToSql(_pid.ToString()+" order by Order_Precedence",FieldType.Integer),NewDao);

        DataRowCollection newDr = Select.Execute().Tables[0].Rows;

            // Get Product Type - Name
            SqlCommand Select2 = new SqlCommand("SELECT ItemID,Product_Type_Name,Product_Type_Footer, Product_Type_Header, Column_Key_Names, Column_Display_Values FROM customtable_Rates_Product_Type WHERE ItemID="+ 
            NewDao.ToSql(_pid.ToString(),FieldType.Integer),NewDao);

            DataRowCollection newDr2 = Select2.Execute().Tables[0].Rows;
                    innerProductTypes =  "\n    {\"Product_Type_Name\" : \"" + newDr2[0]["Product_Type_Name"] + "\" } \n        ";
                    innerColumnKeyNames = ""+newDr2[0]["Column_Key_Names"];
                    innerColumnKeyValues = ""+newDr2[0]["Column_Display_Values"];
                    productTypeFooter = ""+newDr2[0]["Product_Type_Footer"];

        for(int y = 0; y < newDr.Count; y++){
            // add key name and value output elements here for json output.
            innerItems += "\n    {";
            innerItems +="\"ItemID\" : "+ "\"" + newDr[y]["ItemID"] + "\" , \"Daily_Balance\" : "  + "\"" + newDr[y]["Daily_Balance"] + "\" , \"Dividend_Rate\" : "  + "\"" + newDr[y]["Dividend_Rate"] + "\" , \"Annual_Percentage_Yield\" : "  + "\"" + newDr[y]["Annual_Percentage_Yield"] + "\" , \"Period_of_Investment_Dividend\" : "  + "\"" + newDr[y]["Period_of_Investment_Dividend"] + "\" , \"Minimum_Investment\" : "  + "\"" + newDr[y]["Minimum_Investment"] + "\" , \"When_Dividend_Paid\" : "  + "\"" + newDr[y]["When_Dividend_Paid"] + "\" , \"Maximum_Of\" : "  + "\"" + newDr[y]["Maximum_Of"] + "\" , \"Interest_Rate\" : "  + "\"" + newDr[y]["Interest_Rate"] + "\" , \"Points\" : "  + "\"" + newDr[y]["Points"] + "\" , \"Annual_Percentage_Rate\" : "  + "\"" + newDr[y]["Annual_Percentage_Rate"] + "\" , \"Est_Monthly_Payments\" : "  + "\"" + newDr[y]["Est_Monthly_Payments"] + "\" , \"Max_Term\" : "  + "\"" + newDr[y]["Max_Term"] + "\" , \"Max_Amount\" : "  + "\"" + newDr[y]["Max_Amount"] + "\" , \"Max_LTV_Percent\" : "  + "\"" + newDr[y]["Max_LTV_Percent"] + "\" , \"Loan_Type\" : "  + "\"" + newDr[y]["Loan_Type"] + "\" , \"Card_Type\" : "  + "\"" + newDr[y]["Card_Type"] + "\" } \n        ,";
        }     
         innerItems = innerItems.TrimEnd(',');      //this can be done better
         //Output directly the json dataset record.
         Response.Write("[\r");     
         Response.Write("{\r");
         Response.Write("\"pid\": \"1\",\n");
         Response.Write("\"footer\": \""+productTypeFooter+"\",\n");
         Response.Write("\"column_key_names\":[\r" + innerColumnKeyNames + "\r],\n\r");
         Response.Write("\"column_key_values\":[\r" + innerColumnKeyValues + "\r],\n\r");
         Response.Write("\"product_type\":[\r" + innerProductTypes + "\r],\n\r");
         Response.Write("\"items\":[\r" + innerItems + "\r]");
         Response.Write("\r}\r]\r");
      }
```

**Which when called with parameters returns something like this**

```
[
          {
            "pid": "1",
            "footer": "*Annual Percentage Yield",
            "column_key_names": [
              "Daily_Balance",
              "Dividend_Rate",
              "Annual_Percentage_Yield",
              "Max_LTV_Percent"
            ],
            "column_key_values": [
              "foo",
              "bar",
              "dude",
              "test1"
            ],
            "product_type": [
              {
                "Product_Type_Name": "Checking Account Rates"
              }
            ],
            "items": [
              {
                "ItemID": "1",
                "Daily_Balance": "$0.00 - $999.99",
                "Dividend_Rate": "0.00%",
                "Annual_Percentage_Yield": "0.00%",
                "Period_of_Investment_Dividend": "",
                "Minimum_Investment": "",
                "When_Dividend_Paid": "",
                "Maximum_Of": "",
                "Interest_Rate": "",
                "Points": "",
                "Annual_Percentage_Rate": "",
                "Est_Monthly_Payments": "",
                "Max_Term": "",
                "Max_Amount": "",
                "Max_LTV_Percent": "66 month term = 120% of factory invoice plus tax, license, GAP and extended warranty. No additional discounts may be applied. 75 and 84 month financing available at slightly higher interest rates. 48 month term does not qualify for relationship pricing discounts.",
                "Loan_Type": "",
                "Card_Type": ""
              },
              {
                "ItemID": "2",
                "Daily_Balance": "$1,000.00 - $9,999.99",
                "Dividend_Rate": "0.01%",
                "Annual_Percentage_Yield": "0.01%",
                "Period_of_Investment_Dividend": "",
                "Minimum_Investment": "",
                "When_Dividend_Paid": "",
                "Maximum_Of": "",
                "Interest_Rate": "Interest_Rate",
                "Points": "",
                "Annual_Percentage_Rate": "",
                "Est_Monthly_Payments": "",
                "Max_Term": "",
                "Max_Amount": "",
                "Max_LTV_Percent": "",
                "Loan_Type": "",
                "Card_Type": ""
              },
              {
                "ItemID": "3",
                "Daily_Balance": " $10,000.00 +",
                "Dividend_Rate": "0.02%",
                "Annual_Percentage_Yield": "0.02%",
                "Period_of_Investment_Dividend": "",
                "Minimum_Investment": "",
                "When_Dividend_Paid": "",
                "Maximum_Of": "",
                "Interest_Rate": "Interest_Rate",
                "Points": "",
                "Annual_Percentage_Rate": "",
                "Est_Monthly_Payments": "",
                "Max_Term": "",
                "Max_Amount": "",
                "Max_LTV_Percent": "",
                "Loan_Type": "",
                "Card_Type": ""
              },
              {
                "ItemID": "4",
                "Daily_Balance": "<strong>Ultra Rewards Rates<\/strong>",
                "Dividend_Rate": "",
                "Annual_Percentage_Yield": "",
                "Period_of_Investment_Dividend": "",
                "Minimum_Investment": "",
                "When_Dividend_Paid": "",
                "Maximum_Of": "",
                "Interest_Rate": "Interest_Rate",
                "Points": "",
                "Annual_Percentage_Rate": "",
                "Est_Monthly_Payments": "",
                "Max_Term": "",
                "Max_Amount": "",
                "Max_LTV_Percent": "",
                "Loan_Type": "",
                "Card_Type": ""
              },
              {
                "ItemID": "5",
                "Daily_Balance": "$0 - 25,000.00",
                "Dividend_Rate": "0.65%",
                "Annual_Percentage_Yield": "0.65%",
                "Period_of_Investment_Dividend": "",
                "Minimum_Investment": "",
                "When_Dividend_Paid": "",
                "Maximum_Of": "",
                "Interest_Rate": "Interest_Rate",
                "Points": "",
                "Annual_Percentage_Rate": "",
                "Est_Monthly_Payments": "",
                "Max_Term": "",
                "Max_Amount": "",
                "Max_LTV_Percent": "",
                "Loan_Type": "",
                "Card_Type": ""
              },
              {
                "ItemID": "6",
                "Daily_Balance": "$25,000.01 +",
                "Dividend_Rate": "0.02%",
                "Annual_Percentage_Yield": "0.02%",
                "Period_of_Investment_Dividend": "",
                "Minimum_Investment": "",
                "When_Dividend_Paid": "",
                "Maximum_Of": "",
                "Interest_Rate": "Interest_Rate",
                "Points": "",
                "Annual_Percentage_Rate": "",
                "Est_Monthly_Payments": "",
                "Max_Term": "",
                "Max_Amount": "",
                "Max_LTV_Percent": "",
                "Loan_Type": "",
                "Card_Type": ""
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
```

**And finally you would query this script with Ajax/ or jQuery get or even load**

Comment: You can see the full post on my blog here http://chadcollins.com/json-service-output-from-sql-select-using-c/